# Django: login/password management in production?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am newbie in development and in Django in particular.
I have developed a project that is in testing and I am starting to think about production deployement and in particular the initialization of the database and the creation of the users.

I'm not sure which is the simplest and most effective approach ...
I have search on google but I did not find anything on this subject ...

I'm going to have more than thirty user accounts to create at once, so I wrote a script that I will launch on my prodcution database
in addition to managing password hashing (for the moment, I am using a python shell to use the make_password () function and created a valid password) in this script, I am wondering how to send the login / mdp to automate my users.

I did not see an option 'send identifiers by email' in the Django admin interface yet very complete

so I imagine that I have to create an application or at least a script to manage it?

Comment: How is the error message in your question title related to your post?  Do you have existing code you need help fixing?

Comment: sorry, previous post saved not sent...